# Log errors even more verbosely with Symfony2

Tags: php, logging, symfony

I have used the following configuration for my production logging:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        mail:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped
        grouped:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed, buffered]
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        # buffered is used to accumulate errors and send them as batch to the email address
        buffered: 
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: info@....com
            to_email:   info@....com
            subject:    Error Occurred!
            level:      debug
```

This sends emails like this:

> [2012-03-21 21:24:09] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the
>   session [] []
>
> [2012-03-21 21:24:09] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user
>   provider. [] []
>
> [2012-03-21 21:24:09] security.DEBUG: Username "jakob.asdf" was
>   reloaded from user provider. [] []  [2012-03-21 21:24:09]
>   request.INFO: Matched route "_user_settings" (parameters:
>   "_controller": "...Bundle\Controller\UserController::settingsAction",
>   "username": "Jakob.asdf", "_route": "_user_settings") [] []
>
> [2012-03-21 21:24:09] request.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
>   ...Bundle\Entity\User object not found. (uncaught exception) at
>   /var/www/.../vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php
>   line 50 [] []
>
> [2012-03-21 21:24:09] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the
>   session [] []

I would really love to have a stack trace here, or at least the line number in my controller which triggered the error. Otherwise it's really a lot of guessing of what could have gone wrong.

Now, the question: Is there any way to achieve such an even more verbose logging?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it can be achievable.

Create a `ExceptionListener` class.

```
//namespace declarations

class ExceptionListener{
  /**
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface
   */
  private $logger =null;

  /**
   * @param null|\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   */
  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event
   */
  public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
  {
    if($this->logger === null)
      return;
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $flattenException = FlattenException::create($exception);
    $this->logger->err('Stack trace');
    foreach ($flattenException->getTrace() as $trace) {
      $traceMessage = sprintf('  at %s line %s', $trace['file'], $trace['line']);
      $this->logger->err($traceMessage);
    }  
  }
}
```

And then register listener.

```
 kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
  class: FQCN\Of\ExceptionListener
  tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException , priority: -1}
      - { name: monolog.logger, channel: mychannel }
  arguments: 
      - "@logger"
```

You can tweak it as your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

I like the solution from the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-monolog-processor). All you have to do is add the following code to your `services.yml` file:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor }
```

This uses the [`IntrospectionProcessor`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Processor/IntrospectionProcessor.php), a tested processor to add more information to your log. It pulls out the information you care about too probably.