# PHP Uncaught exception gives more details than caught exception

Tags: php, symfony, logging, exception

I build some api endpoint, and trying to work on logging exception, so I purposely remove database and run the endpoint to get PDOException.

My question is, if I did not caught the exception, when I ran the endpoint through postman, it shows me a much more detailed message, stack trace, etc (about 1000 lines),

but if I caught the exception with try catch block something like this

```
catch (\Exception $exception) {
    print_r($exception->__toString());
    print_r("\n\n");

    die;
}
```

It is so much less details. Why is that? and is there anyway to print the same exact data that we got when we don't caught the exception?

Comment: The `$exception` object holds a lot more information than is rendered by the magic __toString() method, just take a look at the actual [object methods and properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) like [getTrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php)

Comment: Look into `debug_backtrace()`. As for the reason why, is that Xdebug is probably enabled, which is a PHP extension that will loop through the results of that function to give you a stack trace.

Comment: And you don't  need to call `__toString()` explicitly; the whole point of the magic method is that it's called implicitly (magically) if you try to echo the object

Comment: @NickJ - no need to use debug_backtrace(); the Exception object already holds the stack trace information

Comment: @MarkBaker so is there anyway I can do smtg like print_r($exception)? I want the same details as when the exception is not caught so I can log it.

Comment: Of course there is; you use the methods available (those listed in the docs page that I linked) to return whatever you want to display.... e.g. `echo $exception->getTraceAsString();` etc

Comment: Isn't this question similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819023/log-errors-even-more-verbosely-with-symfony2)

Comment: see update what I meant about the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have all that data. Exception object has many methods:

```
try {
    // something throwing exception
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getCode() . "\n";
    echo $e->getFile() . "\n";
    echo $e->getLine() . "\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n";
}
```

Read more about `Exception` class:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: This still does not give as much details as, if the exception is not caught.

Comment: What details are you missing?

Comment: is $e->getMessage() also truncated?

Comment: nevermind, I think my updated question is a bit different from my original question

Comment: $e->getMessage() seems to be truncated to 32Kb

Answer (score 1):

You can always throw the exception in the catch block, and let PHP handle. This will let you do something with the exception, then continue the default behavior.

```
catch (\Exception $exception) {
    // Do something with the exception

    throw $exception;
}
```